# Assign vector components to different variables in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to assign the result of an operation to a concatenation of variables in Julia. Something similar to this (although this doesn't work):

```
a = zeros(5)
b = zeros(5)
a, b .= rand(10)
```

Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: Or this `a[:], b[:] = x[1:5], x[6:10]`

Comment: In principle yes, although in my code I don't have x stored as a variable, it is the output of a function. I know I can store it and then index it. I was hoping there was a shortcut.

Comment: I modified the original question, sorry for not explaining clearly.

Comment: 'a[:], b[:] = x[1:length(a)], x[length(a)+1:end]'. But you'll need to store 'x' explicitly as function output. Gah code formatting not working on phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for "vector view concatenation". The idea here is to use [SubArrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/subarrays/#) to build an Array that is actually a view into two arrays. **Julia does not support this out of the box.** The Julia package [ChainedVectors.jl](https://github.com/tanmaykm/ChainedVectors.jl) was built for this, but it is heavily outdated and only works with Julia <= 0.4.

**Not everything is lost**. You have two alternatives:

### Use CatViews.jl

As pointed out in the comments, [CatViews.jl](https://github.com/ahwillia/CatViews.jl) is like ChainedVectors.jl, but works with Julia 0.6 and 0.7:

```julia
Pkg.add("CatViews")
using CatViews

a = zeros(2)
b = zeros(2)
CatView(a, b) .= rand(4)
```

### Build your own solution

With a little work, we can get as good as

```julia
a = zeros(2)
b = zeros(2)
MyView(a, b) .= rand(4)
```

Julia allows you to build your own view-concatenation type. The effort required to build it scales proportional to how general you want it to be. Here is a first attempt that works with vectors:

```julia
julia> # Create a type for a view into two vectors.

julia> type MyView{T} <: AbstractVector{T}
       a::Vector{T}
       b:: Vector{T}
       end

julia> import Base: size, getindex, setindex!

julia> # Define methods to make MyView behave properly.

julia> size(c::MyView) = size(c.a) .+ size(c.b)

julia> getindex(c::MyView, i::Int) = i <= length(c.a) ? getindex(a, i) : getindex(b, i-length(a))

julia> setindex!(c::MyView, val, i::CartesianIndex) = i[1] <= length(c.a) ? setindex!(c.a, val, i[1]) : setindex!(c.b, val, i[1]-length(a))

julia> setindex!(c::MyView, val, i::Int) = i <= length(c.a) ? setindex!(c.a, val, i) : setindex!(c.b, val, i-length(a))

julia> # Test MyView. Define two arrays and put them
julia> # into a single view.

julia> a = rand(2)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.701867
 0.543514

julia> b = rand(2)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.00355893
 0.405809  

julia> MyView(a, b) .= rand(4)
4-element MyView{Float64}:
 0.922896
 0.969057
 0.586866
 0.457117

julia> # Hooray, it worked! As we see below,
julia> # the individual arrays were updated.

julia> a
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.922896
 0.969057

julia> b
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.586866
 0.457117
```

Comment: Thank you both for bringing up CatViews library, I like it   :)

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
a .= x[1:5]
b .= x[6:end]
```

You must tell Julia somehow where to split the vector.

Comment: well, yes, although I was hoping for a single line... and x the output of a function, without storing it explicitly.